# PowerShell Ping to file: Do something if error occurs

Tags: powershell

I have a script that asks for computer name/IP and folder location and then sends continuous pings to that IP and saves the results to a .txt-file. It works perfectly the way I want it to if you get the variables for Location and IP correct.
here's the code that runs:

```
Ping $IP -t|Foreach{"{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date),$_} > $Location\$IP.txt
```

Now I have solved most problems, the issue I am stuck at is that if there's an error that occurs due to the file location being non-existent or unaccessible, I want it to ask for location again, but not sure how.
I've tried using -ErrorAction but to no avail.

Comment: I need some clarification here. Are you expecting the path/file to become inaccessible after the script has started for some reason? Or do you just want the script to validate that the path exists when you start it?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.
I mean that if the user of the script enters an invalid path, or does not have Writing permissions on that path, it will return an error.
What I want is to make that error tell my script to do something else than throw an error and end the script. Or at least send a different message than the standard error message.

Comment: Don't comment on a comment. Put the information Ash wants, the information in your comment, in your question.  `Validate input using PowerShell` might be a better title for your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Invoke-PingContinuous {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]
        $Location,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ipaddress]
        $IP
    )

    # always ask for an existing path
    while (-Not (Test-Path $Location)) {
        $Location = Read-Host -Prompt "$Location not exists, enter again: "
    }

    $outfile = "$Location\$IP.txt"
    try {
        [io.file]::OpenWrite($outfile).close()
        Ping $IP -t | Foreach { "{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date), $_ } | Out-File -append $outfile
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error -Message "$outfile not writable"
    }  
}
```

Then execute like `Invoke-PingContinuous -Location dir -IP 127.0.0.1`.